# The Edit Button Disappears On Backtrack

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, mobile-web

While using SO on my iPhone, I often accidentally click the edit button (I know, tiny button, improbable, ridicule me all you want), or when I click it, I often want to change my mind.  For me, the back button in mobile safari is my 'undo button', but when I do this, and the page reloads, then the edit button disappears!  Reloading the page, starting a new window, clicking the question header all have no effect.  Is this a bug, or intentional?

EDIT:  This only works with other people's questions, not your own (or my own in my case).

Comment: Don't think this is by design.. I'll try reproing later.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't upload pics on my iPhone...  Just try it for yourselves and you'll (hopefully) see what I mean.

Comment: I know, that is annoying, even I don't usually upload screenshots taken from my iPad (sometimes I cheat and force-mobile on desktop to get screenshots). I'll first try force-mobile testing this, otherwise Ill try it on an iphone.

Comment: Facebook has an email address for each group/page that you can send a pic to... I wonder how hard it would be for SE to do something like that...

Comment: Not hard, but there are spam issues. We don't allow pics for low-rep users, and email can't be verified against rep (OK, it can, but the spam issues are still there.)

Comment: I've tried reproing on iOS 7.1.1 with no luck - can you confirm it's still happening and provide more detail?